# Avoid closure in ConcurentDictionary

Tags: closures, concurrentdictionary

I have current function

```cs
        public static ICacheManager GetCacheManager(string cacheManagerName, TimeSpan? expiration)
        {
            var cacheManager = CacheManagers.GetOrAdd(cacheManagerName, keyName =>
            {
                var ret = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<ICacheManager>();
                if (expiration.HasValue)
                {
                    ret.Configure(keyName, expiration.Value);
                }
                else
                {
                    ret.Configure(keyName);
                }
                return ret;
            });

            return cacheManager;
        }
```

JetBrains Rider says there is

```
Closure allocation: 'keyName' parameter + (outer closure of 'expiration' parameter)
```

Well, I know there is override

```
GetOrAdd<TArg>(TKey, Func<TKey,TArg,TValue>, TArg)
```

but how to use it?

How to rewrite this function to avoid closure and pass another parameters to lambda function? What if I need to pass multiple parameters (db query etc.)

Answer (score 0):

This is how you use `TArg` overload:

```
concurrentDictionary.GetOrAdd(key, (k, v) => {
    //do your thing, "v" will be "someVariable"
}, someVariable);
```

So in your case it will be

```
CacheManagers.GetOrAdd(cacheManagerName, (keyName, v) =>
{
    var ret = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<ICacheManager>();
    if (v.HasValue)
    {
        ret.Configure(keyName, v.Value);
    }
    else
    {
        ret.Configure(keyName);
    }
    return ret;
```

}, expiration);

This overload - `GetOrAdd<TArg>(TKey, Func<TKey,TArg,TValue>, TArg)` - simply allows to pass stuff to the factory.